# macOS Calendar adding its own alerts

Tags: macos, calendar, google-calendar

I recently got a MacBook, and I've added a few Google accounts to the Calendar app. Ever since I did, I've been getting alerts about the event after it's already passed or in progress. It seems as though Calendar.app is adding alerts to the event on its own; this didn't happen before I added my Google account to the macOS calendar.

[image]

The only alert that is supposed to be there is ‘Alert ten minutes before start’. Every other alert there has added somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this behavior quite a bit with the calendar application when I dismiss the reminders. More specifically, if you snooze, "remind me tomorrow" or otherwise "kick it down the road", it seems to pick up these additional reminders. This is with a combination of iOS and macOS devices on the same shared calendar.

I think this comes about because you have a reminder several hours or days ahead of the actual event.

Suggestion? If you have something that you want to remind you on a daily basis, instead of kicking the reminder, just set it to a daily repeating reminder instead. That way you can get the benefit of being nagged about it but also you can just dismiss / mark completed today and hear about it again tomorrow without building up the multiple reminders.

Comment: When you say a `daily repeating reminder`, do you mean making another event that exists as just a reminder? Or is that another setting on Google Calendar/macOS Calendar?

Comment: @SheaBelsky it works better with reminders and make it remind you daily repeating. I noticed after I responded that your screen shot indicates a weekly repeat. I think you're picking up these extra notifications because it is a repeating calendar item. I don't think you see this problem when you do this as a weekly repeating reminder/task.

Comment: Sounds good; I'll make those adjustments accordingly. Thank you!